# Rails App - posts view getting error on the each do loop line 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
 : SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0):
1: <h1>Listing posts</h1>
2:
3: <% @posts.each do |post| %>
4:
5: <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
6: <div class="blog-image">
   app/views/posts/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__2193281183502133748_69857822200480'
2 project heroku/router: at=info method=GET path=/products/ host=project.herokuapp.com fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=304 bytes=0
project heroku/router: at=info method=GET path=/ host=project.herokuapp.com fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=0
```

This does work on my local environment, when I pushed it to heroku I get this when going to posts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the controller

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for taking a look. https://gist.github.com/JRizzle88/7666223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should just be doing `@posts = Post.all.paginate...`

The preceding `@posts = Post.all` is unnecessary.

Also make sure you've run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, just a hunch.

Comment: You win this round. We'll meet again young knight